# Assign custom labels to sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a pretty simple question, I think, but I cannot find an answer for it here, or through online searching.

I am running a count query, and am having trouble with value labels and column headings

Query is

```
SELECT
mail_code AS "code",
COUNT(mail_code) AS "count"
FROM data.base
GROUP BY mail_code
;
```

I get back:

```
C       Count
-       -----
Y       110
X       785
Z       92
```

Questions:

1. How do I get the first variable (code) to display its full name, instead of a single letter?
2. How do I change Y, X, and Z to read "phone," "mail," and "email" ...or anything else for that matter?

The length of the mail_code variable is 1 byte...is that why only the first letter is showing up as my varname?

...I was initially warned that based on my title, it might get downvoted. OK, but I tried to look elsewhere for the answer and could not find it, IE I tried due diligence.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `case statement` should solve your problem

Comment: `COLUMN code FORMAT A4`

Comment: Is it 'C' column a char(1)?  Because on [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=881ce1655f40c9deff0f7f5fc61e49e6) works.

Comment: mostly, they keep a look-up table with foreign - primary key relationship. i.e. write explanation in a table with `code_name` and `explanation` columns with values X , phone ; Y, mail : Z , email respectively. And Join them with a SQL statement.

Comment: `DECODE(mail_code, 'Y','phone','X','mail','Z','email') as code` should work for flipping the code to a description. Better yet, store these in a table and join it in so you don't have to write it every time.

Comment: As for you column alias being truncated... that might just be your SQL client. What software are you using?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - case might work but I don't want to create a separate column, I'd like to write something so that value in mail_code changes from 'X' to 'phone'

Comment: @lad2025 - changing to A4 does not return code where it returned only C before

Comment: @McNets - mail_code is char(1), yes

Comment: @JNevill - running free version of Oracle SQL Developer, I believe DB is Oracle 12c

Comment: Try by CAST it to char(10)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly, they keep a look-up table with foreign - primary key relationship. i.e. write explanation in a table with `code_name` and `explanation` columns

with values `X , phone` ; `Y, mail` : `Z , email` respectively,

and Join them with a SQL statement :

```
select d.mail_code as "code", c.explanation as "communication type", count(1) as "count"
  from data_base d inner join codes c on ( d.mail_code = c.mail_code )
 group by d.mail_code, c.explanation;
```

Where DDLs are as following to create tables :

```
create table codes(mail_code varchar2(1) primary key,explanation varchar2(15));
create table data_base( mail_code varchar2(1) references codes(mail_code));
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80d381/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I got about 75% of the way there.

Syntax:

```
COLUMN mail_code FORMAT A10
SELECT
    DECODE (mail_code,
        'X', 'mail',
        'Y', 'phon',
        'Z', 'emai') AS "code",
COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM data.base
GROUP BY mail_code
;
```

Returned

```
code    count
----    -----
mail    110
phon    785
emai    92
```

Double quotes are needed b/c Oracle. It'll work to change name to 'code' wo double quotes but comes up as all caps (CODE) wo them, and I can choose w double quotes.

Thank you all for your help with this!

Comment: Just a remark, if I may: avoid using double quotes when naming *anything* in Oracle. You won't benefit from it, but might (and will) give you headache later. There's no problem in, for example, creating a table whose columns names will have mixed case (using double quotes, right?), but you'll **have to** specify those names every time using double quotes, and not fail in typing because the result will be an error. Seriously, get rid of double quotes. No problem in presentation layer - most reporting tools allow you to use custom headers anyway.

Comment: Good to know, thank you for the advice, Littlefoot. I've done analytics for a long time but am a somewhat noob to SQL, this is helpful. Thank you !